# Using Solspace Form to add users to a mailing list

Tags: solspace-freeform

I trying to get solspace form to add users to a mailing list, but no cigar. using the latest free version. any help is appreciated.

```
{exp:freeform:form form_name="mailing_list" mailinglist="blog" return="contact/thank_you" notify="xx@gmail.com" required="email"} 
<form action="" id="contactForm" type="post">
    <input type="email" name="blog[2]" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address."  maxlength="100" class="form-control" id="email">

    <input type="submit" value="Send Message">

{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: Can you please let us know if you are receiving any errors or what is happening when you try it? From your code above, you have a <form> tag inside the tags, which shouldn't be there. The exp:freeform:form tag adds the opening and closing form tags for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your input fields need to be structured similar to this one below:

{freeform:field:email attr:type="email" attr:class="form-control" attr:placeholder="Your Email Address"}

Take a look at the example for the advanced form found here:
http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#advanced_contact_form

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use parameters that are for Freeform 3.x. Mailing list is now a fieldtype. You will need to add it to your form and adjust its settings when you create the field.

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/#mailinglist